# shebang line not working in R script

Tags: r, ubuntu, shebang

I have the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

print ("shebang works")
```

in a file called shebang.r. When I run it from command line using Rscript it works

```
$ Rscript shebang.r
```

but when I run it from the command line alone

```
$ shebang.r
```

It doesn't work. shebang.r command not found.

If I type (based on other examples I've seen)

```
$ ./shebang.r
```

I get permission denied.

Yes, Rscript is located in /usr/bin directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the file executable.

```
chmod 755 shebang.r
```

Comment: It worked! Are there other options besides 755 that work? I'm planning to sharpie the command on my laptop. Thanks.

Comment: @Milktrader: what is necessary is that the person trying to run the file have execute permission on it. Read the man page for `chown` and the section of the `ls` man page on the "Long format" (i.e. `ls -l`).

Comment: Anything that sets the executable bit for the owner should work, as long as you are the owner of the file. Minimally, you need `100`, but then you won't be able to read or write it anymore. You probably want at least `700`, which gives the owner read, write and execute permissions, but denies all permissions to everyone else (except root).

Comment: thanks all for the chmod MAN page reference. It has all the info I need

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sjoerd's answer... Only the directories listed in the environment variable `PATH` are inspected for commands to run. You need to type `./shebang.r` (as opposed to just `shebang.r`) if the current directory, known as `.`, is not in your `PATH`.

To inspect `PATH`, type

```
echo $PATH
```

To add `.` to `PATH`, type

```
export PATH="$PATH:."
```

You can add this line to your `~/.bashrc` to make it happen automatically if you open a new shell.

Comment: yes, I do need to use ./shebang.r to get it to work. I was told that adding . to the PATH variable introduces security risk, but I might do it anyway since it's my personal computer and it's not like I have missile launch codes on it.

Comment: The security risk is that you might be in a directory where someone else put, say, a program named `ls` that you might accidentally execute. If `.` is last in your `PATH`, the risk is pretty small, because the usual `/bin/ls` will take precedence, and `.` will only be searched in the case of a nonexistent command. Still, I'd recommend against adding `.` to the `PATH` of the root user, because the potential damage is greater. See further https://listman.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/1999-July/msg01969.html